# Is it possible for me to access a specific MSBuild argument from within a XAML build template?

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

first time posting so apologies in advance.

I'm fairly new to builds and have been challenged with the task of migrating some old 2010 builds  in preparation for a move to TFS 2015 at the company I work for.

I have been mostly successful, but have had to resort to Powershell to perform some tasks, as the solutions that are being built are so old. While this was easy enough to accomplish; I've hit a snag. We have several branches in our source control, and the builds I'm moving ideally need to able to run against any of them. Currently I'm having to create duplicate builds running duplicate Powershell scripts for each branch, because I'm having to explicitly define the folder structure in the Powershell script for each branch.

So what I'm trying to do is use an MSBuild Argument with the name of the branch in it so I can pass that as an argument in the build template to the Powershell script, meaning I can use one build for any of the branches. My only problem is I can't seem to work out how to access an individual build argument property and pass it to the script.

So, for example, if my build arguments are "p:/Branch=Development /p:Configuration=Release /p:/DeployOnBuild=true", is there any way in the XAML workflow I can access the value in the "Branch" parameter?

Apologies if I've waffled; If I can clear anything up then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are they moving to TFS 2015 instead of TFS 2017? 2017 still has backwards compatibility with XAML builds. Your best bet is to start migrating those XAML builds to the new build system ASAP, since XAML build support is ending.

Comment: Because the rest of the business uses TFS 2015, and then there's us in the corner forcing them to keep a TFS 2010 server running.

Our builds are a mess quite frankly, and once we are on TFS 2015 we will be looking at recreating them from the ground up using VSTS, but in the meantime I was given until the end of next week to get our ancient solutions and their ancient builds building in TFS 2015. 

The world won't collapse when we get migrated now, but it would be nice not to have to create 5 builds for 6 solutions just because each solution needs to be runnable on any of our branches.

Answer (score 1):

The MSBuild arguments are passed in the MSBuildArguments property. If you are looking to extract a particular parameter e.g BranchName, you would need to parse it in your XAML. You could either do that or add another property for passing the Branch Name.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I might go about doing that? I've actually found a couple of custom activities written by a previous member of our team that already extract the value I need, but they use it within the code. I need to return that value (again I can do that with the code I found) and use it further down but I just don't know how then to interact with it in the XAML template. Can I put that value into a build variable? Or interact with some sort of output value from the previous activity in the workflow?

Comment: sorry for late reply. didn't sign in earlier. You might find this link helpful http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/properly-incorporate-msbuild-arguments.html